# Is it correct to use zero article before 'mechanic' and 'hairdresser' in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to not use an article before the occupations in this sentence?

> Two 18-year-olds, Ron Smith, mechanic, and George Major, hairdresser, were arrested yesterday.

Comment: For the sake of brevity, it's ok and not too uncommon; but more typical would be to use the indefinite article.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  This usage treats their occupations as titles and is common in journalism where words equal page space.

The lack of spaces after the commas is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Depends where the sentence is. It's newsreader concise.  If it was in the New Yorker, they'd add a "a". ;-)

Comment: Do you mean "newsreader concise"?

Comment: Thanks for quick response. No, l don'. I have just seen this sentence in a grammar book, and I was really confused.

Comment: Your comments and modifications are really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use an *appositive*. Typically, you'd use an article when the appositive follows the proper noun, but you wouldn't use one when the situation is reversed:

Here are four variations (with spaces added after the commas, a convention not subject to debate):

**Proper noun as appositive; note the article before the profession:** 
Two 18-year-olds, a mechanic, Ron Smith, and a hairdresser, George Major, were arrested yesterday.

**Profession as appositive with article:** 
Two 18-year-olds, Ron Smith, a mechanic, and George Major, a hairdresser, were arrested yesterday.

**Your example: Profession as appositive without article, but I would argue that, without the article, the uses here are best viewed as adjectival, in which case they are indeed permitted:** 
Two 18-year-olds, Ron Smith, mechanic, and George Major, hairdresser, were arrested yesterday.

**Adjectival profession, standard form and actually more concise:** 
Two 18-year-olds, mechanic Ron Smith and hairdresser George Major, were arrested yesterday.

Comment: _Two 18-year-olds, a mechanic, Ron Smith, and a hairdresser, George Major, were arrested yesterday._ is ambiguous. Better is _Two 18-year-olds – a mechanic, Ron Smith, and a hairdresser, George Major – were arrested yesterday._