# Appositive with no definite article

Tags: definite-articles, appositives

> Hans, **head of a company that manufactures garden furniture**, is announcing to his staff ....

Shouldn't it be *the head of a company ...*? Is that correct? Could you explain why we do not need a definite article here?

Comment: What is the source of the prescription or presumption that an appositive needs an article? Can you cite your sources?

Comment: Related/ Possible Duplicate: *
Is it correct to use zero article before 'mechanic' and 'hairdresser' in this sentence?*  https://english.stackexchange.com/q/277518/14666

Comment: "Head of a company .." cannot be an appositive modifier since it cannot be substituted for the matrix NP, i.e. "head of a company that manufactures garden furniture, is announcing to his staff ...." is ungrammatical as a sentence.

Comment: @BillJ: Are you saying that the quote is ungrammatical (I don't think it is), or are you saying that "Hans, head of a company that manufactures garden furniture, is announcing to his staff" doesn't contain an appositive? If you're saying that "head of a company that manufactures garden furniture" is not an appositive, then what is it? The answer by John Lawler that I linked to in my answer here seems to indicate that the product of whiz-deletion can be called an appositive NP.

Comment: @BillJ: Could you post an answer to [How to differentiate appositive clause from a relative clause?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/363109)

Comment: @sumelic Bare role NPs cannot be appositives. in the OP's example "head of a company that manufactures garden furniture" is unable to take over the subject function.

Comment: @BillJ: So what is it? And what is the basis for your statements (I tried to research this a bit, and I wasn't able to find a consensus supporting your assertions).

Comment: @sumelic As I said, it is a supplementary NP, an additional unit of information, but not an appositive for the reason I gave above.

Comment: @BillJ: [Heringa (2011)](https://www.lotpublications.nl/Documents/294_fulltext.pdf) says "appositions have the properties of nominal predicates, not of arguments" (p. 76). Do you disagree with this, or have I misunderstood something about it? Is an "apposition" a different construction from an "appositive"? (As far as I can tell, Heringa simply uses "apposition" as a noun and "appositive" as an adjective)

Comment: @sumelic Apposition simply describes the relationship between the appositive NP and the head noun. An appositive NP must be capable of replacing the entire matrix NP. Compare: "I took my wife to see the opera Carmen", where "Carmen" is the appositive modifier. It can replace the matrix NP to give "I took my wife to see "Carmen", and thus qualifies as an appositive NP.

Comment: @BillJ: OK, I think I get the idea of how you use the terms "appositive/apposition". It's a bit frustrating to me that you don't seem to engage with any sources that are brought up that might contradict your use of the term (either the ones that I mentioned, or the ones that Shoe mentioned in the linked thread). Unless you can tell me why your definitions and analyses are better than others, I can't fully trust what you're saying. If there are linguists who use "appositive" differently from the way you use it, I'd prefer if you acknowledged that so that everyone can avoid confusion.

Comment: @sumelic. McCawley on p. 467 of _The Syntactic Phenomena of English_ summarizes the issue well: _"Various authors have proposed criteria for identifying a combination of two expressions as 'apposition', the most popular ones being (i) that the two expressions have identical reference; (ii) that they be of the same syntactic category; (iii) that either of them can be omitted without affecting the acceptability of the sentence; and (iv) that either of them can be omitted without affecting how the remaining constituents are interpreted."_

Comment: McCawley goes on to say: _"There is little consensus as to the appropriateness of (i-iv) as criteria for 'apposition' or with regard to how to apply the criteria ..."_ What I derive from the discussions above and elsewhere is that in future references to 'apposition' I will refer to McCawley's comment about the lack of consensus on this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Certain phrases that function like titles can be used without the definite article in certain contexts. See [Araucaria's answer to *Why “be king”, not “be a king”?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/246528/77227)

This usage is most commonly encountered in predicative contexts (e.g. "He is president/President of the United States"), but it can also be found in appositives, as in your question. I suppose this could be explained in terms of the ["whiz-deletion" analysis of appositive NPs](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/382413/77227): "Hans, head of a company that manufactures garden furniture" could be seen as being derived at some level from the longer phrase "Hans, **who is** head of a company that manufactures garden furniture".

### This might not be categorized as an "appositive" construction

BillJ left a series of comments suggesting that "head of a company that manufactures garden furniture" should not be called an "appositive" because it does not work as a substitute for the subject "Hans". According to BillJ, it should be called a "supplementary NP" instead.

BillJ's comments seem to be based on some particular analysis/definition of "apposition" (summed up by the statement "An appositive NP must be capable of replacing the entire matrix NP"), but I don't know exactly what literature would discuss the arguments for using this definition/analysis. There seems to have been some debate about the syntax of appositives and related structures; Shoe left a helpful comment linking to a related discussion beneath [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/441274/77227).

One article that seems relevant, but that I haven't been able to read yet, is "Nominal Apposition", by N. Burton-Roberts, 1975. From what I gather, Burton-Roberts reserves the term "appositive" for things that aren't derived from reduced relative clauses.

There may also be relevant information in "[Appositional constructions](https://www.lotpublications.nl/Documents/294_fulltext.pdf)", a 2011 thesis by Herman Heringa. I haven't finished reading it, but from what I've read so far, it looks like analyses that treat appositives as a type of reduced relative clause are not dead yet: Heringa says

> O’Connor (2008) [...] argues that appositions underlyingly are non-restrictive relatives with a null relative pronoun as its subject.

(p. 14)

Heringa also discusses things that he calls "appositions" that lack an article (the examples are taken from Dutch, not English, but seem analogous to your example) on p. 78, and mentions that Doron, E. (1994) ‘The discourse function of appositives’ uses examples like this as part of an argument that "appositions behave as nominal predicates" (p. 76).

Whatever you call it, the structure in your quote is grammatical.

Comment: I don't see any article warranted in the structure, titles or no titles, exempted or not.

Comment: Per the logic, *who is* does not change the requirement or otherwise of an article.

Comment: Good answer. There is another discussion on the definition of "apposition / appositive" in the comment section here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/441265/what-is-the-grammatical-term-of-whose-wife-was-a-school-teacher/441274#441274